# Creating contour maps in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I am trying to change the ggplot2 layout of the contour so I can include colors in the different rings and make it appear as if it had a higher altitude. Is there anything I can add on the code below?

```
ggplot(df3,mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  stat_density_2d()
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a twofold question and the "looks like altitude" is a no. I think Hadley is philosophically opposed to pseudo-3D.

Comment: Yes, you can do, for example: `ggplot(df3 aes(x,y)) +
  geom_density_2d(aes(colour=..level..)) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="red", high="blue")`

Comment: should I include another variable for `...level...`

Comment: Yes the one that has information on the "height" you want to be simulated as altitude